# BASH - If else, Regular expression, OR

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement

My bash script is supposed to check if the user inputs two numbers. Each number should be preceded by either a `+` or a `-` sign. The first number should be four digits long, and the second number should be five digits long.

No matter what values I enter, the output is always `Fail`

Command-line statement to run the script:

```
$me add +1234 -12345
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script name add
if [ $1 != [\+\-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ] || 
   [ $2 != [\+\-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]
  then
    echo Fail
else    
    echo Success
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

POSIX-style tests (`[`) don't perform pattern matching at all. The `!=` operator is a string comparison. ksh-style tests (`[[`)) perform  pattern matching with reglular shell patterns using the `==` operator, and ERE matching with `=~`. (There is no `!=~`, but we can DeMorganify)

```
! [[ $1 =~ [-+][[:digit:]]{4} && $2 =~ [-+][[:digit:]]{5} ]]
```

To perform pattern matching in POSIX sh, the only option is the `case` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way (I was wrong, [there is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12876376/1535516)) to do pattern matching using `if` statement. `case` can be used for such things. Working example:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script name add

case $1 in
    [+-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) r1='success' ;;
    *) r1='fail' ;;
esac
case $2 in
    [+-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) r2='success' ;;
    *) r2='fail' ;;
esac

if [ $r1 = 'fail' ] || [ $r2 = 'fail' ]
then
    echo Fail
else
    echo Success
fi
```

Comment: You absolutely can use pattern matching with if, see my answer.

Comment: && will execute the next command as long as the previous one does NOT fail. || will execute the next command if the previous one DOES fail. Which does work. Just not the way that I would construct it, but doesn't make it incorrect. My bad :) I deleted my previous (incorrect) comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double brackets to enable advanced functionality that is more similar to traditional programming languages. For instance, to use `||` instead of `-o` and `&&` instead of `-a`. **Double brackets are also required in order to perform pattern (matching**.

Also, brackets should be used for the *entire* expression, not for each sub-expression separately and should include the `||`.

I would use a line like:

```
if [[ $1 == [+-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] && 
      $2 == [+-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] ]]
  then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

**EDIT**: using `==` instead of `!=` (why be so negative?) and to remove references to regex (uses pattern matching).

Comment: @tripleee not true, see the edit to my answer to see how you're wrong. Did you test it out before making silly statements?

Comment: @DavidDraughn That means shell glob patterns, not regular expressions. Citing the ABS as factual information should never be done. It's wrong about many things. See the `PATTERN MATCHING` section of your bash manpage. Your example can be made to work properly with extglob enabled.

Comment: Learn something every day. My apologies, @tripleee

Comment: What's the problem here? You were right the first time, @DavidDraughn. The only mistake was in using the term "regex", though "pattern match" is also used (the code is valid as both regex and shell pattern). "Globbing" technically means only "filename expansion", but they are often used interchangeably. I prefer what you have now, but also `[[ $1 != pat || $2 != pattern ]]` and `[[ ! $1 == pat || ! $2 == pat ]]` are exactly equivalent. Both `==` and `!=` match shell patterns. Neither match regex. Beginning in Bash 4.1 alpha, extglob patterns are forced on within `[[` for `==` and `!=`.